# Node.js Express express.json and express.urlencoded with form submit

Tags: node.js, express

Express (or Connect's) bodyParser middleware is marked deprecated and users are advised to use instead:

```
app.use(connect.urlencoded())
app.use(connect.json())
```

However, when I run the an example from *Node.js in Action*, I use curl to fill out the form as suggested by the book:

```
curl -F entry[title]='Ho ho ho' -F entry[body]='santa loves you' http://abc:123@127.0.0.1:3000/api/entry
```

It doesn't work. `req.body` is not defined. Am I missing something? It works fine with bodyParser.

**EDIT: SOLUTION as of Express 4**

Parse json this way:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Parse urlencoded body this way:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Then there is no deprecation warning. The extended: true (default) uses the qs module and false uses the querystring module to parse the body.

Don't use `app.use(bodyParser())`, that usage is now deprecated.

Comment: As of express `4.16.0`, you don't need the external `body-parser` dependency anymore, and can parse with `app.use(express.json());` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` (source: https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3423)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`bodyParser` is in fact the composition of three middlewares (see [documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) and [relevant source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.9.0/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js)): `json`, `urlencoded` and `multipart`:

- `json` parses `application/json` request bodies
- `urlencoded` parses `x-ww-form-urlencoded` request bodies
- and `multipart` parses `multipart/form-data` request bodies, which is what you're interested in.

If you only specify `json` and `urlencoded` middlewares, the form data won't be parsed by any middleware, thus `req.body` won't be defined. You then need to add a middleware that is able to parse form data such as formidable, busboy or multiparty (as stated in [`connect`'s documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html)).

Here is an example, using [`multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty):

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
app.use('/url/that/accepts/form-data', multipartMiddleware);
app.post('/url/that/accepts/form-data', function(req, resp) {
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
});
```

Don't forget that by using such middlewares you allow anyone to upload files to your server: it then your responsibility to handle (and delete) those files.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that multipart is deprecated as well.

Comment: You can look into an alternative such as busboy or formidable then :) The API isn't exactly the same though

Comment: I've added a solution to the question.