# How to prevent Multer File Upload when input validation fails

Tags: node.js, express, multer, joi

I'm creating a (POST) route to handle file uploads and also store some other properties to MongoDB in addition to the file path. The problem is when input validation fails, the file is still uploaded in the static(uploads) folder.

I'm using the Multer middleware for file uploads.

Setup

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    //rejects storing a file
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

Fields

```
const seamUpload = upload.fields([
  { name: "stylePicture", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "materialPicture", maxCount: 1 }
]);
```

Route

```
router.post("/", [auth, seamUpload], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateSeam(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const seam = new Seam({
    stylePicture: req.files["stylePicture"][0].path,
    materialPicture: req.files["materialPicture"][0].path,
    description: req.body.description,
    deliveryDate: req.body.deliveryDate,
    customer: req.body.customerId
  });

  await seam.save();

  res.send(seam);
});
```

[Client(PostMan) Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezg42.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me as you faced with this problem.
one solution that I found is when your authentication in all modes seems error, in that case if you have a file from client, you can easily remove it like this:

```
    if(req.file) {
       fs.unlink(
             path.join(__dirname, "go to root folder that 'req.file.path' leads to the file", req.file.path),
                (err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

or then in case that you got multi files, you should do the same way for each of them. If there is, I glad to here that.

I wish there be another way by using multer package for handling that.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can have the validation middleware BEFORE the multer middleware.
That way, when the validation fails, all the subsequent middlewares would not be executed -- and thus, the files will not be uploaded.

Separate out the validation like so:

```
const validateSeamUpload = (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = validateSeam(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    return next();
};
```

And then, mount this `validateSeamUpload` BEFORE the `seamUpload` middleware like so:

```
router.post("/", [auth, validateSeamUpload, seamUpload], async (req, res) => {
    /** No need for validation here as it was already done in validateSeamUpload */
    const seam = new Seam({
        stylePicture: req.files["stylePicture"][0].path,
        materialPicture: req.files["materialPicture"][0].path,
        description: req.body.description,
        deliveryDate: req.body.deliveryDate,
        customer: req.body.customerId
    });

    await seam.save();

    res.send(seam);
});
```

By the way, you can pass them as arguments to `post()` as well. Like so:

```
router.post("/", /** => See, no need for an array */ auth, validateSeamUpload, seamUpload, async (req, res) => {
    /** your controller code */
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What request did you make? Which client did you use? Any relevant code snippets? Edit your questions to include all these

Comment: I made a post request to the Seam endpoint and it returns a validation error customerId is required. Then, I tried logging the req.body in the console but it was an empty object. I'm using Postman Client(type: form-data)

Comment: But does the file gets saved in case of validation error?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Then, it solves the problem right? When the validation failed, the file was not saved!

Comment: But then, it will prevent multer from parsing the multipart data before validation.

Comment: May I ask a specific scenario in which you want multer to parse the data before the validation? I mean what is wrong in multer parsing the data and saving it to a file once the validation is done

Comment: The Object from the client is in the multipart format (form data), and because of this I need a multipart parser(busboy, multer etc.) to parse the object. Without parsing it, I'm unable to get the object in the server, so I can't even perform validation

Comment: That is not quite correct. Multer only parses the files. Are you using `express.urlencoded()` and/or `express.json()` ? It would be very helpful for me if you post a screenshot of the Postman from which you are making the request

Comment: Makes sense. Where are you mounting `express.urlencoded()` middleware?

Comment: Nowhere, I'm not using the express.urlencoded() middleware.

Comment: That is why the body is not being parsed. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143105/node-js-express-express-json-and-express-urlencoded-with-form-submit)

Comment: I am using express.urlencoded() for form-data, console logs req.body as empty object. This happens after separating the validation using a middleware. It was working fine before separating the validation. Any ideas?